# Using two asterisks to add a file in git

Tags: regex, git, wildcard, glob, git-bash

I want to add a file which has a unique file name but a long preceding path (e.g. a/b/c/d/filename.java). Normally I would add this to my repository by doing

`git add *filename.java`.

However I have also done this before:

`git add a/b/c/d/filename*`

So I tried to combine the two:

`git add *filename*`

but this does something weird. It adds every untracked file. I can see possible reasons for failure but they all should occur in one of the previous two commands so I don't know why this is happening.

My question isn't so much about how to add a file to a git repository with just its file name (although that would be useful).
My question is what is my misunderstanding of the `*` operation which makes me think the above should work.

Info:

I am using [Git Bash for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com/), which is based on [minGW](http://mingw.org/).

Comment: Is the filename you were using actually the string `filename` or are you using that as an example?

Comment: That is just an example.

Comment: If you are referring to the last command then that is not what is happening. In fact I think the opposite is happening: it is matching everything. If I type `git add` then nothing is added.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking at [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) 
(not regular expressions, which are a different pattern-matching language), and they're expanded by your shell, not by git.

If you want to see how they're going to match, just pass the same glob to another command, eg.

```
$ ls -d *filename.java
```

vs

```
$ ls -d *filename*
```

(I've just added the `-d` so ls doesn't show the contents of any directories that match)

---

Since you're using git bash, and it's possible that glob expansion behaves differently from a regular shell, try

```
$ git add --dry-run --verbose -- *filename*
```

for example: this should show you how it really expands the glob and what effect that has.

Note the `--` ... if you're using globs that *might* match a filename with a leading `-`, it's important to make sure git knows it's a filename and not an option.

Unfortunately, this will only show you the files which both match the glob, and have some difference between the index and working copy.

---

**Answer from author:**
The dry run helped a lot, here is what I found:

I was forgetting about the bin folder which I haven't added, so when I performed the dry run I realised it was finding two matches: filename.java and filename.class. When I changed the glob to `*filename.j*` it worked.

My next step was to remove the .class and try the command again: it worked! It is still unexplained why git bash added everything when it found two matches... since the dry run behaves differently from the actual run I think there must be a bug, but I think that discussion is to be held elsewhere (unless somebody thinks it isn't a bug).

Comment: Interestingly this gives me different results. So does this mean Git is evaluating it?

Comment: Git can't evaluate it, Globing happens before Git is run (in all shells I know of)

Comment: That might be the problem: I am using Git Bash which is a Git shell for Windows (which I think uses minGW). I will add this to my first post.

Comment: OK, I've added alternate method to examine the real glob expansion that should work for git bash ...

Comment: I have added my explanation to this answer because I wanted people to be able to see my answer, but also accept Useless's answer as it was what lead me to figure it out. Once my edit has been peer-reviewed you should be able to see it. Thank you all!

Comment: BTW, it's probably sensible to add `*.class` to a `.gitignore` file, assuming you never want them committed.

Comment: Yeah I have been meaning to get around to doing that, just haven't been bothered. Thanks :).

Comment: @Paul: Git actually can and does evaluate globs, if it gets them intact in it argument list. This could happen if you quote a glob-containing name (e.g. `'*filename*'`), or if there was no filename matching the glob specified on the command line. Strangely, it seems to interpret `'*filename'` to mean "anything ending with `filename` in any directory", but it doesn't do that with `'*/*filename'` or `'**/*filename'`, as I would have expected.

Comment: @echristopherson have you considered adding an answer? Your solution is what I was looking for when I came to this question

Answer (score 4):

You could try with `git add ./**/*.java`

Note: I tested with zsh, it should also work for bash as well.